# What is wrong with this piece of date formatting code using MomentJS?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

Below code is self explanatory but it's not working as expected. In case of 0 day difference, it's returning '0y ago'

```
const formatTime = (time) => {
    const dayDiff = moment().diff(moment(time), 'days')

    switch (dayDiff) {
        case dayDiff == 0:
            return `${moment().diff(moment(time), 'hours')}h ago`
        case dayDiff > 0 && dayDiff < 31:
            return `${moment().diff(moment(time), 'days')}d ago`
        case dayDiff > 31 && dayDiff < 365:
            return `${moment().diff(moment(time), 'months')}m ago`
        default:
            return `${moment().diff(moment(time), 'years')}y ago`
    }
}
```

In case time falls on the same day then it's ending up in the default case when it should end in the first case and return '0h ago'.

I probably missed something minor. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: That is not how you use switch. Get rid of switch and use if/else if/else

Comment: You are also sort of recreating https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/02-fromnow/

Comment: @epascarello thank you for sharing this link. I was not aware something like this already exists in Moment. I'm gonna use this instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch is meant for a comparison to a value. To make your code work it would need to be

```
switch(true) {
  case dayDiff == 0:
  ....
}
```

But that is considered bad practice to use conditionals in a switch, just use if statements

```
const formatTime = time => {
  const dayDiff = moment().diff(moment(time), 'days')
  if (dayDiff == 0) {
    return `${moment().diff(moment(time), 'hours')}h ago`
  } else if (dayDiff < 31) {
    return `${moment().diff(moment(time), 'days')}d ago`
  } else if (dayDiff < 365) {
    return `${moment().diff(moment(time), 'months')}m ago`
  } else {
    return `${moment().diff(moment(time), 'years')}y ago`
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thank you @epascarello. I've always been told that in case of long if-else statements, it makes sense to use switch-case but good to know there are certain cases in which if-else would work better.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, the [switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) evaluates the values of the cases, a chain of conditionals may suit your case correctly, try something like this:

```
const formatTime = (time) => {
    const dayDiff = moment().diff(moment(time), 'days')

    if (dayDiff == 0) {
        return `${moment().diff(moment(time), 'hours')}h ago`
    }
    if (dayDiff > 0 && dayDiff < 31) {
        return `${moment().diff(moment(time), 'days')}d ago`
    }
    if (dayDiff > 31 && dayDiff < 365) {
        return `${moment().diff(moment(time), 'months')}m ago`
    }

    // this would be your "default"
    return `${moment().diff(moment(time), 'years')}y ago`
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you @GMaiolo. I've always used switch-case as a replacement for chain of conditionals because I thought they work as a replacement for the same. But good to know switch-case would work better in this scenario.